# jQuery addClass removeClass animation when div is display none

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Its possible to combine jQuery **addClass** with animation when the div is **display:none** ?

**jQuery**

```
 $(window).scroll(function() {
        $(this).scrollTop() > 100 ? $(".nav-current").addClass("hide") : $(".nav-current").removeClass("hide");
        $(this).scrollTop() > 100 ? $(".nav-affix").addClass("show") : $(".nav-affix").removeClass("show");
        $(this).scrollTop() > 50 ? $(".navbar").addClass("go-top navbar-fixed-top") : $(".navbar").removeClass("go-top navbar-fixed-top");
    });
```

**CSS**

```
.show {
    display: block;
}

.hide {
    display: none;
}

.nav-affix {
    display: none;
    > li {
        > a {
            font-size: 12px !important;
            transition: all 0.3s;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: So you're not really asking about jQuery, but rather about CSS `transition` with `display:none`?

Comment: Yes but    display: property not working with transition. Second solution   visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0; but it's not a solutions in this case.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` instead of the transitions?

Answer (score 3):

Agree with **fauxserious** - you can use fadeIn and fadeOut jQuery functions to achieve your goal.

**One more option** is using `width(1000)` and `height(1000)` where argument (1000) is a duration in milliseconds, thus you could get some animation.

*Let me know if you still have an issue.*

Comment: Hi @Vnuuk. Thanks for your answer. But I do not know exactly what you mean.
Because i use this script for show & hide navbar inner content. And when i scroll down not look exactly good without some animation. I Am trying to add .animate({opacity}).. but doesn't work. I have created a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wh8xeLcd/) . Thanks